# Ngx-uploader responses

Tags: php, angular, file-upload, ngx-uploader

What responses (JSON and HTTP statuses) should I return on successful/unsuccessful file uploads when using [ngx-uploader](http://ngx-uploader.com/)?

eg.

```
HTTP 401
{{error: {code: 5; message: Not authorized}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to upload on the demo, and the script returned a json of the uploaded files:

```
[{
    "fieldname":"file",
    "originalname":"25508884_1667581309951575_499158447_o.png",
    "encoding":"7bit",
    "mimetype":"image/png",
    "destination":"/app/dist/api/uploads",
    "filename":"bkjo3l.png",
    "path":"/app/dist/api/uploads/bkjo3l.png",
    "size":1926691
}]
```